# Is there an easy way to initialize a simple class without a constructor?

Tags: c++

I have a very simple class, like this:

```
class MySimpleClass
{
public:
    uint16_t   m_myInt;
    String     m_myString;
    String     m_myOtherString;
    MyEnum     m_myEnumValue;
    bool       m_myBool;
};
```

This class is part of a pre-compiled library that I can't change, and it doesn't offer a constructor. Is there any way that I can initialize this class *without having to do something like this...*

```
MySimpleClass msc;
msc.m_myInt = 1;
msc.m_myString = "foo";
msc.m_myOtherString = "bar";
msc.m_myEnumValue = ENUM_VALUE_YES;
msc.m_myBool = true;
```

I'm not averse to doing it that way, but I'm curious to know if there's some kind of initialization syntax that will do it?

I'm working in C++03, but answers in C++11 will be of interest as well.

Comment: You can make it a struct (not sure if this is even necessary) and use field initializer syntax as known from good old c: `MySimpleClass msc = { 1, string("foo"),...};`

Comment: IMHO, the most elegant way in such case is to create a child class that inherits from this class, and implement the constructor for the child class however you choose to...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ:  That is an answer not a comment - you should have posted it as such.  You are right it is not necessary to make it a struct.  In C++ a struct is identical to a class in every way except for default member visibility and default inheritance (public in both cases)

Comment: @EitanT: Ditto - also worthy of being an answer if you include an example.

Comment: Since the class is an aggregate, you can use the traditional list initialization, which should work out just fine.

Comment: @Clifford Of course it is, but I was just to slow. If there weren't other answers already adressing this well when i finished writing, I would have posted it as such. (Interesting BTW, s.o. critiques comments being answers and not vice versa ;) ...)

Comment: @EitanT It is a matter of opinion, but I would say using inheritance here is the most inelegant solution.

Comment: @juanchopanza Hence the "IMHO". Might I ask why you think so?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Mods can convert answers into comments, but not vice-versa, so flagging those answers is the better path

Comment: @EitanT I think it is an abuse of inheritance, confusing, and I see no benefit.

Comment: @Izkata I well know. I just stated it's interesting that s.o. critisised the other way round. I usually avoid to post additional answers, if they don't add essential information that wasn't already given in other answers.

Comment: @juanchopanza The benefit of inheritance here is that you can prevent misuse. For example, you can force initialization if you make the default constructor private, or you can also implement it and allow automatic initialization during dynamic allocation. You can also further extend encapsulated functionality of the class by adding member functions if necessary, which (again, IMHO) would look way nicer than to create separate functions for that.

Comment: @EitanT Again, all of that is an abuse of inheritance. This might look elegant in Java. And dynamic allocation could be dangerous. You certainly couldn't delete a derived object via a base class pointer.

Comment: @EitanT It would be undefined behaviour, because the base class has no virtual destructor.

Comment: @juanchopanza If you use private inheritance, this should be no problem.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Then the derived type *is not a base type*, in which case you might as well rewrite the original class from scratch because you're cannot using it anymore in client code.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can add a free function that you can use as a constructor:

```
MySimpleClass make_msc(
    uint16_t myInt,
    String myString,
    String myOtherString,
    MyEnum myEnumValue,
    bool myBool)
{
    MySimpleClass msc;
    msc.m_myInt = myInt;
    msc.m_myString = myString;
    msc.m_myOtherString = myOtherString;
    msc.m_myEnumValue = myEnumValue;
    msc.m_myBool = myBool;
    return msc;
}

//Usage:
MySimpleClass msc = make_msc(1,"foo","bar",ENUM_VALUE_YES,true);
```

Alternatively, you can use aggregate initialisation:

```
MySimpleClass msc = {1,"foo","bar",ENUM_VALUE_YES,true};//C++03 or C++11
MySimpleClass msc{1,"foo","bar",ENUM_VALUE_YES,true}; //C++11 only
```

---

Note: The

```
MySimpleClass msc = {1,"foo","bar",ENUM_VALUE_YES,true};
```

form can only be used in a declaration, but the:

```
MySimpleClass{1,"foo","bar",ENUM_VALUE_YES,true}
make_msc(1,"foo","bar",ENUM_VALUE_YES,true)
```

forms can be used in any expression that expects a `MySimpleClass`.

Comment: +1 For the free function solution: The only solution that is remotely robust if the library vendor should ever decide to change their struct layout.

Comment: The free-function is an excellent solution! Is the declaration-only form C++03 compatible?

Comment: @ComicSansMS - Do you know what happens with the declaration-only syntax when the struct changes? Would there be a compiler error or would it be undefined behaviour of some kind?

Comment: @KarlNicoll: Either you would silently initialise the struct in the incorrect order, or there would be a compilation error.

Answer (score 14):

Uniform initialization in C++11 is useful

```
MySimpleClass x {1, "foo", "bar", NUM_VALUE_YES, true};
```

Answer (score 8):

A bit late in the game, but I think a more elegant way would be creating a sub-class that inherits from the class `MySimpleClass`, and implement its constructor to suit your needs.

For example:

```
class MyImprovedClass : public MySimpleClass
{
public:
    MyImprovedClass(uint16_t myInt, String myString, String myOtherString,
        MyEnum myEnumValue, bool myBool)
    {
        m_myInt = myInt;
        m_myString = myString;
        m_myOtherString = myOtherString;
        m_myEnumValue = myEnumValue;
        m_myBool = myBool;
    }
};
```

and then use it, *e.g*:

```
MyImprovedClass msc(1, "Foo", "Bar", ENUM_VALUE_YES, true);
```

So far as `MyImprovedClass` concerns, it can be passed as `MySimpleClass` and treated the same. Another benefit here is that you can *force* initialization by making the default constructor private, *e.g*:

```
class MyImprovedClass : public MySimpleClass
{
public:
    MyImprovedClass(uint16_t myInt, String myString, String myOtherString,
        MyEnum myEnumValue, bool myBool)
    {
        // Implement as above...
    }

private:
    MyImprovedClass() {}
};
```

On the other hand, if you choose to implement a default constructor for the "improved" class, you could have this class automatically initialized during dynamic allocation. Should you choose so, you can add a copy constructor, or even extend (and encapsulate) its functionality by adding more member functions, and keep things tidy.

Comment: Could result in a memory leak if the destructor needs to be virtual and isn't declared so in the base class.

Comment: @Matt for this specific case I don't think it's dangerous, the base class is simple, as no dynamic allocations are done during its construction.